# MySQL `WHERE ` is giving unexpeted results for matching 0

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have `user_info` table description as follows

```
Field          Type         null Type        Extra
usr_id     int(11)           NO  PRI           auto_increment
f_name     varchar(50)       NO         
l_name     varchar(50)       YES            
user_name  Varchar(45)       NO         
password   varchar(128)      NO         
email      varchar(50)       NO         
type       enum('a','s','c') NO
```

**Data inside table**

```
0   admin   admin   admin   d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    admin@oww.com   a
1   staff   Staffer staff   d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    staff@oww.com   s
2   staff2  stafer  staff2  d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    staff2@oww.com  s
10  Shanoop Pattanath   shan123456  5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8    shan@shan.com   s
```

**SQL query**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (`user_info`)
WHERE
    `user_name` = 0  -- wrong input 
        AND `password` = 0 -- wrong input
ORDER BY `usr_id`;
```

**Result for this query**

```
0   admin   admin   admin   d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    admin@oww.com   a
1   staff   Staffer staff   d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    staff@oww.com   s
2   staff2  stafer  staff2  d033e22ae348aeb5660fc2140aec35850c4da997    staff2@oww.com  s
```

how come this query matching with all data ? this query should not give any result, should it ? what wrong I have done here ? detailed answers well appreciated  **MySQL ver : 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 (Ubuntu)**. [SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ad0c/1)

> All username,password and emails are just imaginary

**Update**
I know that `0` must be inside quotes. I solved this problem by making like that. But how come MySQL give this wired output. ?

Comment: like your question.... really good and weird query output

Comment: Adding quotes around the 0 (`'0'`) fixes the issue, you should do that.

Comment: @user1153551 This  almost caused huge security issue in my sites. Did I found new way to **SQL injection** ?

Comment: @FDL I know that but why this gives this result ?

Comment: Because you're comparing an integer to a string value. It's likely that when SQL casts the string to an integer to compare it, it casts as 0. Which then matches.

Comment: @FDL Why no SQL error ? and Why it skipped last row ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the comparison being performed is an `int` to an `int`.

MySQL is converting the text in `user_name` and `password` to an `int` for comparison purposes.  The MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) indicates that `varchar` will be converted to `int` in this kind of operation.

If you take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63ad0c/29) you will see that using `CONVERT` on the `user_name` and `password` field to make them `int` will output 0, hence making your comparison true.

If you mean to do a comparison of two `varchar` values, make sure that you surroung your criteria with single-quotes:

```
user_name = '0'
AND password = '0'
```

Great question btw!

Comment: Wow I didn't know this , Thanks a lot for this knowledge.
 `select  '5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8' = 0;` is giving 0 that is why last row skipped. Is there any way that we can avoid this kind type casting ? I think this may cause sql injection. When we user code Igniter input class.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/22180).

The thing is `user_name` is a `varchar` while `0` is an `INT`.
You cannot compare a `INT` and a `String`.

By practice you should put it in qoutes like:

```
`user_name` = '0'  -- wrong input 
 AND `password` = '0' -- wrong input
```

But if you would like to make sure that the compared data will always be a string.
You can try something like:

```
 WHERE `user_name` = CAST(0 AS CHAR);
```

---

If you would do

```
SELECT *
FROM supportContacts
WHERE type = 1;
```

It wont return anything.

Why? This is because it is converting your column to an integer. Any field without a valid integer will equate to 0. You should make sure that you only compare string fields to string values.

Comment: yes thanks for answer, this question also confusing for me. now ok

Comment: @majimboo When we try matching wrong data type it must give SQL error. Instead this give results. And funny thing is it is not giving last row, Did you notice  it ?

Comment: @Shanoop yes, it is odd. Even on fiddle it can be replicated. But this is probably because the int given is `0`. Will look into it more.

Comment: this is MySQL burg ?? i try this on PostgreSQL its return type cast error.

Comment: @user1153551: MySQL prefers returning "*some result that might be what you meant*" over throwing an error and telling you that you are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @majimboo Any field without a valid integer will equate to 0 . This statement is wrong. Please remove that `select  '5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8' = 0;` if your statement was right then this should give 1 instead this give 0. **I think conversion is done like this if fist char is not int then whole is 0 . otherwise the first int character value will be that whole value**

Comment: `select  CAST( '5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8' AS UNSIGNED);` This give 5 instead if your statement was right it should give 0